# Engrave, Boolean Modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers

[image]how are you?
.
i am modeling a soap with engraved text on it, as shown in the attached image.
but when i use the Boolean modifier on the soap with the wanted text the whole mesh of the soap mess up as you see,
so please can you help me to solve this issue.
thanks in advance.[image: soap modeling]

[image]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: yes sure i can, but how please ?

Comment: use the site I've linked, and copy paste the address of this blenderstackexchange page as it is asked

Comment: DONE
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5754" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5754/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a way to do it, tell me if it's clear:

[image]

Comment: hello dear, i will try it now then will tell you of it works with me because the one i want to emboss is a logo not just a text, anyway i will try it .
thank you very much.

Comment: so you should have given us the logo, but anyway it should not change anything

Comment: hello dear, 
actually it doesn't work with the logo, BTW it a typeface logo not an icon. 
but how can i show you screen shots about the result i reached.

Comment: you can edit your question

Comment: hello again, i added a picture showing the logo wanted to engrave it on the soap. and how it looks with subsurface modifier,
and please if i can contact you to know more. thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, it would be too tedious to explain by mail or on a forum   :/   please follow the exact same method than the one I've used, if it looks too hard perhaps come back to more basic 3D exercices and tutorials

Comment: i searshed a lot on youtube about tutorials, but almost of them are showing little complexion than my logo words.

Answer (score 0):

That is for maybe isolated vertex, or duplicated ones, if your topology is some how low poly try to correct all those vertex-issue.