# can anyone help me with me carving a ring

Tags: modeling, armature

hi i need help to carve a ring, i got the ring down to the proportion i needed but i would like to engrave it with celtic runes. my original idea was to create two seperate object  here's the ring:[image: ring] ,here's the runes:[image: runes]

what i thought of doing was put the runes at the same circumference of the ring and then boolean it.

but thats were im stuck, does anyone know how to make them in to said circle thank you

Comment: hello, for this kind of work I tried to give an answer here, maybe it will help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129013/engrave-boolean-modifier

Comment: thank you so much, you really saved my life XD