# Problems engraving text

Tags: modifiers

beginner here.

I am creating a part to be 3D printed. I am trying to engrave text on it so that it will appear in low relief, but the boolean operation does not seem to be working. The surface on which I am engraving is like a very flat cone, so I am first applying shrinkwrap to make the text follow its curvature.

The model I am working on has had the text engraved before, but there is a problem, and I have to do it again. So I removed the old text and filled-in the missing areas.

These are the steps I am following:

I made the text in Adobe Illustrator
I converted it to outlines and exported it as SVG
I import the SVG into Blender
I join the curves (ctrl-j)
I make a mesh from the curves
I select the option "subdivide" from the W menu
I apply shrinkwrap modifier, using the cone-like shape as the object
I extrude the text.
I remove doubles (through W menu)

Now, when I make a boolean operation on the cone, using the text mesh as the object it only carves the surface partially, some letters are totally missing and some are partly carved.

[image]

I've been going around this website looking for ideas but none I found works for me. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Axel

Comment: I made an answer, tell me if it helps: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129013/engrave-boolean-modifier

Comment: ..or, since this is a printing project, and you can probably afford the polycount, you might want to take a [displacement approach](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/122473/35559)

Answer (score 2):

I used the boolean difference method as described on the boards as well, but it can do funky stuff to your geometry if, for example, you were engraving the inside of a cylinder (like a ring). Instead, I prefer to go into UV editing mode, select the faces where I want the text to be, then unwrap the UVs to a new map. From there you can export the UVMap or import the image you exported from Illustrator and apply it to the UVMap. Now, apply the image as a texture to the object, add a displacement modifier and apply the texture to the UVMap.
[More on displacement modifier here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/materials/components/displacement.html) there are tons of tutorials to be searched for.