# Curving text around cone for 3D printing (requires clean geometry)

Tags: bezier-curves, 3d-printing, text-object

I'm having difficulty figuring out create text that curves around a cone, and then removing that text mesh from my cone so I can have a cone shape with the text debossed in it for 3D printing.

I see tutorials out there for doing this in a way using the shrinkwrap modifier - This works to a small extent but I end up with geometry that I can perform a boolean difference to deboss the text.

Does my text have too little subdivisions or something? Does anyone have a workflow for this? I feel like it should be quite simple but I'm just not fluent in Blender enough to get this to work.

Comment: I guess once you have booleaned you need to rework a bit, for example does this answer? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129013/engrave-boolean-modifier