# Blender text not being properly applied onto cylindrical object

Tags: modeling, modifiers, text-object

After creating "circular" text and applying it to a cylindrical object the imprint has a slope:

[image]

[image]

The object is a regular extruded cylinder:

[image]

Comment: you probably need to rework your topology, maybe take a look at this question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129013/engrave-boolean-modifier

Comment: I tried the solution there and managed to project the text onto the cylinder but it's barely visible

Comment: what I meant is that you probably need to rework your topology

Comment: Can you add more vertexes locally without redoing the entire model? E.g. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193569/projected-text-barely-visible

Comment: the boolean has created ngons and stretched triangles, thus the artifacts, you need to recreate a clean topology, see the link, you need to rework a bit with join, knife, etc... I'm not sure you can avoid it... another solution would be to "fake" the 3d letters with bump node or normal node, but it really depends on the final purpose

Comment: It should look like: https://www.crucialfitness.co.uk/media/catalog/product/cache/1f29d024c5869e21508462f482692cc1/g/r/grip-2_7.jpg . I'll try to change the topology of the middle cylinder only (create a different object; reapply shader). I tried both the diff modifier and knife project. Would it be faster to do everything with bumps?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112699/discussion-between-moonboots-and-sebi).

Comment: Yes if you don't need it to be in real 3D, do it with bump, you can bake the extruded letters then unwrap this part of your cylinder and give it a bump node, it will be much faster than rework the topology