# Normal map not applied to selected faces

Tags: modeling, uv, node-editor, uv-image-editor, text-object

Following:

[Blender text not being properly applied onto cylindrical object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193563/blender-text-not-being-properly-applied-onto-cylindrical-object?noredirect=1#comment324406_193563)

I've created a normal map with text that I tried to apply onto a cylindrical shape:

[image]

[image]

Strangely, what happens is:

- parts of text appear onto faces onto which the texture (material) has not been applied to
- the UV map of the central selected faces seems to extend way outside the map
- moreover, the selected faces are not scalable on X (height never changes; they can only be scaled on Y); no matter for how long I scroll the selected faces (line) over the map does not seem to have an "end"

Why?

[image]

Added map to .blend:

[image]

Text appears mirrored on the cylinder:

[image]

Fixed! Text had to be remapped and rescaled to X -1:

[image]

Comment: Seems to be due to the UV map. But as several "strange" issues, you'd better upload your file. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @lemon Thx! Done!

Comment: Well... all is scalable (but from some ortho point of view, this is not visible). About the UV map, redo it for the part you want to set the normal map. Select the faces where you want the text to be and UV unwrap it. The normal map is not included (packed) in your file, so I can't show anything here.

Comment: Additionally, as the other material is also based on a UV map, you may want to create a second UV map for the text part.

Comment: as Lemon says you need to unwrap again, but before, make a U (Unwrap) > Reset

Comment: @lemon I did; almost there (the text is mirrored and applied to a few different (unselected) faces. How do you pack the normal map into a .blend file.

Comment: @lemon Done! Reuploading in a second.

Comment: to pack the UV map, in the UV editor (with the map shown) go to the menu "image/pack"

Comment: @lemon Yes, I have a separate UV map for the text; I unwrapped it as a cylinder and now the text is applied onto it but it's mirrored.

Comment: As you have already a UV map used for the other part of the mesh. Create a second one and for this one select only the mesh part where you want the text to be and unwrap it.

Comment: If mirrored: scale the UV on X of -1 (and about the file, still no image in it)

Comment: @Sebi, so you did it! Great!