# How can I engrave this Text on the side of this cylinder (without changing the style of the font)?

Tags: modeling, topology, text-object

Another day another question: I want to engrave this "EXPERIMENT" text on this cylinder like object. The text has to wrap around the object (not completely, only the amount it covers). It is important that the font style is not changed at all during the process. It would also be good if the topology is 3D printable/clean.

What is the best way to do this?

The cylinder like object:

[image]

The "EXPERIMENT" text should be engraved on the side of the cylinder:

[image]

What is the best and cleanest method to do this, without changing the style of the font at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also see my answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129013/engrave-boolean-modifier).

Create your text, rotate 90° on X, apply the rotation, put the origin at its geometry, convert to mesh, <kbd>X</kbd> > Limited Dissolve in order to clean the mesh, create a plane, loopcut vertically, remove the faces only, select the text, switch to *Edit* mode, select all, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> left click to select the grid, choose the front view and header menu > *Mesh > Knife Project*:

[image]

You should end up with this topology, which will allow you to bend it:

[image]

Give your text a *Simple Deform* modifier / *Bend* mode, here 90° on Z, put it in front of your cylinder (probably use a cylinder with more vertices):

[image]

Now use the knife project tool on the cylinder with the text as knife object, here is what it will give:

[image]

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> in order to extrude the faces along their normal (maybe you'll need to rework the topology a bit, particularly if you apply a *Subdivision Surface* modifier):

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135985/discussion-on-answer-by-moonboots-how-can-i-engrave-this-text-on-the-side-of-thi).