# How can I engrave text on a cylinder where the text is part of the mesh and the subdivision surface modifier can be used?

Tags: modeling, topology, text-object, font

I am finding it really hard to engrave text onto the outside of a cylinder (i.e. rounded surface), while also using subdivision modifier and keeping the font style the same. The problem is, that the font of the text has to stay the same (i.e. the style cant be lost) and the surface has to stay even and rounded. Also everything has to be part of the same mesh. I am having problems with that as the vertical edges going across the cylinder make keeping the font style the same hard. However if I dissolve the edges then the rounding of the cylinder is changed.

Does anyone have a good technique to solve this issue? On youtube the only tutorials I can find dont use the subdivision modifier or are not rounded objects.

EDIT: The object/ text relationship should be as demonstrated here: [How can I engrave this Text on the side of this cylinder (without changing the style of the font)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/262301/how-can-i-engrave-this-text-on-the-side-of-this-cylinder-without-changing-the-s?rq=1) (i.e. text is engraved accross the lenght of about 1/4 of the circumference of the cylinder and has about a 10% margin to the top and bottom of the cylinder) only with the added constraint that it has to be a subdivision surface model.

Comment: Check this answers, I think they discuss exactly what you want to do: - [How can I engrave this Text on the side of this cylinder (without changing the style of the font)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/262301/how-can-i-engrave-this-text-on-the-side-of-this-cylinder-without-changing-the-s?rq=1) - [Engrave, Boolean Modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129013/engrave-boolean-modifier) (and subdivision modifier).

Comment: I asked the question. The solution doesnt involve applying a subdivision surface modifier, which is the tricky bit. If I apply a subdivision surface modifier the solution doesnt work. One can try to retopologize it however I run into so many probems, its almost impossible to get a clean look.

Comment: On the second answer it is applied a subdivision surface modifier on the last step. Maybe it would help if you add some screenshots to your question.

Comment: Yes but in the second answer the font is very small compared to the object which makes the retopology job much easier. I have font versus size of the object like in the first question/answer. I.e. the text bends around about 1/4 of the length of the circumference of the cylinder and there is only about 10% of spacing between the top and bottom edge of the cylinder and the text.

Comment: Alberto, the problem is as demonstrated in the first question you cited. Only with the added constraint that it has to be a subdivision modifier model.