# How to cut text as boolean to subdivision cylinder?

Tags: subdivision-surface, text-object, boolean-modifier

I'm trying to figure out how can I make the text extend the cylinder inwards so It creates effect like there is carved out text into that cylinder.
Any help?
[image]

[image]

[image: Reference]

Comment: the easiest way would be to use a normal map if it doesn't need to be carved for real

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44758/emboss-text-onto-curved-surface https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6226/whats-the-simplest-way-to-wrap-extruded-text-around-a-cylinder https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/262301/how-can-i-engrave-this-text-on-the-side-of-this-cylinder-without-changing-the-s